# Magento 2.4.1: Image in the Magento admin category editor doesn't appear in the site's category page

Tags: magento2.4.1

Recently upgraded to Magento 2.4.1. The image in the Magento admin category editor doesn't appear in the site's category page. Also, some text that appears in the sites category description doesn't show up in the category editor. Is there any sitting in Magento admin controlling the display of the image for the category page? Below is the image as seen in the Admin, which doesn't appear on the live site in the category page.

[image]

Comment: by default, if you load images and add text data in the description field of a category, it will be displayed on frontend. afaik there is no default configuration that would manipulate the visibility of the description, but 2 things pop into my mind that could affect the display: 1. using a custom theme or having customizations on the frontend side; 2. the description value is set at store view level, so maybe the value is not assigned in the proper scope (like it's set at website level and at storeview level you have another one)?

Comment: Yes, you are right about 2. the description value is set at store view level, so maybe the value is not assigned in the proper scope (like it's set at website level and at storeview level you have another one) This helped fix the issue

Comment: If you answer this post, I will be happy to accept it as answer.

Comment: hi there, glad to help :) I will add this as answer then so others can use this too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that as confirmed by @CodeForGood, the category description attribute scope was the lead to fix the issue:

> the description value is set at store view level, so maybe the value
> is not assigned in the proper scope (like it's set at website level
> and at storeview level you have another one)

So whenever display differences occur between what is set in the admin and what is displayed, the first thing I suggest checking is the values on other scopes in the same website-store-storeview hierarchy as it is possible that the value you are setting is overwritten at a higher level.

Comment: Hi Diana, could you please help me understand what is the use of scopes like All Store Views, Main Website and Default Store view? Thanks. This has been a bit difficult for me to understand

Comment: hi there, sure :) i recommend you read https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/stores/websites-stores-views.html and https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/configuration/scope.html and all the 'Scope' subpages you can access from the left-hand side. I can't think of a better resource for getting a grasp on scopes. good luck!